# Head across the pond

Tags: meaning

The crossword puzzle clue today was "Head across the pond?" and the answer was "Loo". Does anyone understand that?

Answer (score 5):

"Loo" is a slang term for toilet in the UK, "Head" is a naval term for the same item, so presumably this is a crossword published in the US (which is across the pond from the UK).

Comment: Trivia: "Head" is called such coz originally it was located at the head , or front, of the ship. Simply a cutout in the hull, it was there so whilst taking a dump one did not feel the wind blowing up their fanny, or worse, blowing it all back in their  face.

Comment: @Cascabel always remembering the difference between a US fanny and a UK one :D

Comment: @Mynamite Oh, my word...never thought about that. I was trying to avoid the use of _bum,_ actually, to make it more understandable  to our friends in the US. Gotta love the differences...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I never would have guessed that!

Comment: (::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)(::)